# Точка входа для консольного приложения

Tags: c++

Зачем при создании консольного приложения писать комментарий

> ... определяет точку входа для консольного приложения

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Комментарии вообще никак не обрабатываются компилятором, так что вы можете смело писать программы вообще без комментариев. В том числе и без этого, приведенного вами.

Если уверены, что через пару лет вспомните, что делала ваша программа и зачем она вообще была написана...

Comment: Почему тогда при использовании шаблона консольного приложения в `Visual Studio` этот комментарий автоматически добавляется?

Comment: @qwerty Для начинающих, например. Как напоминание :) Функциональной нагрузки он не несет никакой.